# My java chat client only sends strings when the dataStream is closed

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I created a java chat application (client and server)
Everything works fine when I'm on my LAN (using LAN IP address of the server into my client).

But when I'm using the Internet address of my server in my client, the strings are sent only when I close the output Data stream of my client (and all the strings are sent at once).

Here's a quick snap of my code (I have port forward from 6791 to 6790 in the example below),

My server (thread):

```
// this line is actually on my global server class, used below with theServer
ServerSocket svrSocket= new ServerSocket(6790);
//wait for incoming connection
connectionSocket = svrSocket.accept();
connectionSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
// free the accepting port
svrSocket.close();
//create a new thread to accept future connections (creates a new svrSocket)
theServer.openNewConnection();
//create input stream
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
boolean threadRunning = true);
while (threadRunning) {
  //System.out.println("thread: in the while");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
    System.out.println(clientSentence);

    }
    catch...
 }
```

My client:

```
InetAddress dnsName;
Socket clientSocket;
PrintWriter out;
dnsName = InetAddress.getByName("myAddress.me");

clientSocket = new Socket(dnsName.getHostAddress(), 6791);

Thread.sleep(10);


out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true );
int i=140;

while (i>130){
    try {
        out.println(Integer.toString(i));
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    i--;
        }
out.flush();
out.close();
clientSocket.close();
```

I've tried with DataOutStreams, there's nothing to do.
My server will only receive the strings when `out.close()` is called on client side.

Is there a reason why, over the Internet, the data stream *has* to be closed for data to be sent? Is there a way around this? Am I doing something wrong?